# Django - add a form into a fieldset in django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

is it possible to add a form to a fieldset view in django Admin?

admin.py

```
class ConfigTemplateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = VariableForm
    list_display = ('device_name', 'date_modified')
    fieldsets  = (
            ('Switch Details',{
                'fields' :  (
                                ('device_name',),
                                ('config','remote_config'),
                                (form)
                            )
            }),            
        )
```

the above gives me the error:

```
sequence item 0: expected string or Unicode, ModelFormMetaclass found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`fieldsets`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets) option what you're asking it's not feasible. The `fields` inside `fieldsets` must be of type `str` or `unicode` and not a callable one. They must match your model fields.

To overcome your problem you may [override the `change_form.html`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) template and add there your form.